# How to add left sidebar to CMS pages?

Tags: cms, cms-block

I am using Magento 1.9.2.1 with "porto" theme.

I have created a few CMS info pages for things like "reasons to buy" etc. I have the pages set to 2 column with left sidebar but there is nothing showing in the sidebar.

How can I add blocks like recently viewed / categories etc to the CMS pages using Layout Update XML as it looks a bit empty at the moment!

Just to add I am not a coder, I have extremely limited and basic knowledge so to anyone that does reply please treat it as an "idiots guide" lol

Answer (score 2):

Catalog -> Manage Categories -> [select category] -> Custom Design

Put this code snipet to 'Custom Layout Update' textarea:

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="reports/product_viewed" before="-" name="left.reports.product.viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml" />
</reference>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but nothing changed. The cache isnt enabled, I added the code to layout XML update, saved and refreshed on the front end and nothing.

Btw, this is for a CMS page, not a category page. I added the code to the CMS page. Is the code different for that as the answer posted refered to category pages.

Comment: Maybe this block is removed? Change block name and see what happens. Do you see anything in error log?

Answer (score 0):

CMS >> pages >> [select cmspage] >> Design >> in "Layout Update XML" text area add the below code for show recently view product on products on left site bar on selected CMS page:-

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="reports/product_viewed" before="-" name="left.reports.product.viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml" />
</reference>
```

For add category block in CMS page please add below code in "Layout Update XML" text area:-

```
<reference name="left">            
            <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.category" before="-" template="catalog/category/category_nav.phtml"/>
            <reference name="catalog.leftnav">
                <action method="unsetChild"><child>category_filter</child></action>
            </reference>
</reference>
```

After that On line no 37 in \app\design\frontend\smartwave\porto\template\catalog\category\category_nav.phtml file
you need to comment below code because this not work on cms page.

```
<?php echo Mage::registry('current_category')->getName(); ?>
```